# Can I use Ionic Framework to create a mobile optimized website (not just a mobile app)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobile, ionic-framework

I have been doing research to figure out the best way to create a mobile optimized website using Rails variants.  I see that Framework 7 does this nicely, but I can't figure out if I can also do this with Ionic Framework?  Can I use ionic components to create a mobile website that runs in a plain browser like Safari?

Answer (score 0):

As Ionic works with AngularJS and according that the development process uses a simple http server on the folder /www, you can easily develop a mobile website with Ionic.

You will not have to use Cordova/Ionic plugins. But you'll can use HTML5 API to get geolocation or webcam access, etc.

But it is not because you can that you have to. Give it a try and tell us if you think it was a good idea.